# VBA - Use dialog box to prompt user to pick a sheet from a dropdown list?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

Right now, my code uses a dialog box to prompt the user to choose a file, and then another dialog box to choose a sheet from within that file. When the sheet is chosen, it copies over a bunch of data from that sheet. The code works, all is well.

The thing is that the way that it prompts the user to choose a sheet is by manually typing it in. It would be great if instead it displayed a drop-down list with all the sheet names for the user to choose from. I'm not sure if this is possible. For simplicity, what I'd want to happen is:

1. User is prompted to and chooses a file
2. Drop down list appears with all the sheet names within the chosen file.
3. Upon choosing a sheet, the entire sheet is copied and pasted into the workbook where the macro was executed.

My working code:

```
Sub ImportData()
Dim w As String, wb As Workbook, FileSelected As String, wsDest as Worksheet, wsSrc as Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
     .Title = "Choose File"
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
     If .Show <> - 1 Then Exit Sub
     FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Set wsDest = ActiveSheet
set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileSelected)

w = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
On Error Resume Next
Set wsSrc = w.Worksheets(w)
On Error GoTo 0

If wsSrc is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Sheet '" & w & "' was not find in " & wb.Name
Else
     wsSrc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A4")    'unnecessary if I just copy the whole sheet over
End If

wb.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How many sheets to chose from in worst case ? what is the longest sheet name ?

Comment: That's easy enough. Instead of InputBox() you need to use a form, with a combobox on it. Loop the `wb.Worksheets` collection to get all sheet names and add them to the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a 'select one from multiple' solution 'on the cheap'. It will only work if you have a limited number of options (in your case, Worksheets) to select from (anything more than 20 or 30 starts to make the dialog too large). If you have a greater number of Worksheets than that, then the solution noted by @Andre (UserForm with a ComboBox) is the correct way to go (in fact, is the solution I myself would prefer ... but is more complex ... but I'm happy to update this answer with some guidance on how to implement that solution if you do need it).

So, firstly, add the following Function in a standard Module in your VBA project ... you could put it in the same Module as your `ImportData` Sub if you wish. The Function has header comments explaining what it does and the limitations it has ... please read these comments before using it! It is also commented within it to explain what it is doing. Note also that the Function is not limited to selecting Worksheets ... if your project requires the user to make a single selection from multiple options then you can re-use the Function.

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Allow the user to make a single selection from multiple options ... note that:
'     * The maximum length of text that can be shown to the user is 1023 characters including the initial text and the
'       list of options ... text will be truncated (and, so, options not displayed) if longer than this
'     * The number of options that can be shown is limited only by the size of the dialog and the height of the screen,
'       so realistically need to limit to around 30 items ... but better with much less!
' Parameter vOptions (Variant): The options to select from ... a 1D array of primitive (Strings, numerics etc) types
' Parameter sText (String): What is being selected from eg "Select an option"
' Parameter sTitle (String): Optionally, title text for the dialog ... if omitted, will be the name of the host app
' Returns (Long): The index number selected by the user (this will always be the index within the supplied array, not
'     necessarily the index displayed to the user in the dialog) or -1 if the user did not select a valid option (eg
'     pressed 'Cancel', did not enter a number, entered an invalid number, entered text etc) and so you should not use
'     arrays with negative indexes with this Function
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function InputBoxSingleSelect(vOptions As Variant, sText As String, Optional sTitle As String = "") As Long
    ' get some values relating to the supplied array
    Dim lMax As Long, lOffset As Long
    lMax = UBound(vOptions) - LBound(vOptions) + 1
    lOffset = 1 - LBound(vOptions)
    
    ' construct the text to show to the user, including the list of options
    Dim i As Long, sMsg As String
    For i = LBound(vOptions) To UBound(vOptions)
        sMsg = sMsg & vbNewLine & CStr(i + lOffset) & ": " & vOptions(i)
    Next i
    sMsg = sText & ", enter a number from 1 to " & lMax & vbNewLine & sMsg
    
    ' show the dialog to the user and get the response
    Dim sReply As String, lReply As Long
    sReply = VBA.InputBox(sMsg, IIf(Len(sTitle) = 0, Application.Name, sTitle))
    
    ' get the response as an index of the supplied array, or fail gracefully
    On Error GoTo invalidReply
    InputBoxSingleSelect = -1
    lReply = CLng(sReply)
    If lReply >= 1 And lReply <= lMax Then
        InputBoxSingleSelect = lReply - lOffset
    End If
invalidReply:
End Function
```

Next, replace the 4 lines in the code in your question from `w = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")` to `On Error GoTo 0`, inclusive, with these lines:

```
Dim sNames As String, wks1 As Worksheet
For Each wks1 In wb.Worksheets
    sNames = sNames & wks1.Name & "["  ' [ cannot be used in Worksheet names so is safe to use as a delimiter here
Next wks1
Dim lIndex As Long
lIndex = InputBoxSingleSelect(Split(Left$(sNames, Len(sNames) - 1), "["), "Select a Worksheet")
If lIndex <> -1 Then
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets(lIndex + 1)
End If
```

... these lines build a String of each Worksheet name delimited by a '[' characters (which cannot be used in Worksheet names) which, having removed the final '[' using the `Left$` and `Len` functions, we then `Split` into an array to pass to the `InputBoxSingleSelect` Function. We get the value back from `InputBoxSingleSelect` and get a reference to the appropriate Worksheet if the user made a valid selection (a 'not valid' selection results in a returned value of -1).

Comment: This is a pretty cool "I really don't want to create a separate form for this simple selection" function. I like it.